# Selenium+python: Waiting on changes in style

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

On page I have HTML element which changes after a few seconds (to few minutes) from:

```
<div style="opacity: 1; width: 100%;" id="progressbar-overlay" class="wings-progressbar-overlay"></div>
```

to:

```
<div style="opacity: 0; width: 0%;" id="progressbar-overlay" class="wings-progressbar-overlay"></div>
```

It's part of loader.
I want to wait till this element change.

I've tried with this:

```
element = self.check_element(By.ID, "progressbar-overlay", "Progressbar wasn't displayed", tekst)

    for x in range(0, 120):
        if element.value_of_css_property("opacity")==1:
            print element.value_of_css_property("opacity") + " not yet"
        else: 
            print element.value_of_css_property("opacity") + " end"
            break
```

but result is:

> ### 1 en.
>
> Ran 1 test in 23.021s
>
> OK
>   d

Why doesn't it work and how to wait on this element's change?

Comment: Use a debugger and check the value of  element.value_of_css_property("opacity") ... I suspect that it is returning a string, but you're comparing it to an integer 1, not a string "1"

Comment: you have right :) But now it cause error: "StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the  following example. This function will wait till your second div appears in DOM.

```
import time
...
...
def wait_for_complete_page_load(browser, total_wait=100):
    try:
        elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@style, "opacity: 0")]')
    except:
        total_wait -= 1
        time.sleep(2)
        if total_wait > 1: wait_till_page_loaded(browser, total_wait)
```